# How to locate elements with certain attributes using XDocument.Descendants

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have written this test code to read in a XSL data file and locate `link` elements:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                XName qualifiedName = XName.Get("link", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("d:\\test.xsl");
                foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants(qualifiedName))
                {
                    XAttribute attrRel = element.Attribute("rel");
                    XAttribute attrType = element.Attribute("type");
                    XAttribute attrHref = element.Attribute("href");

                    if (attrRel == null || attrType == null || attrHref == null)
                        continue;

                    if(attrRel.Value == "stylesheet" && attrType.Value == "text/css")
                        Console.WriteLine(attrHref.Value.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is working OK. The `link` elements are standard HTML. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Workbook-S-140-PublicTalk-WatchtowerStudy-ServiceTalk-Videoconference2.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Workbook-S-140-PublicTalk-WatchtowerStudy-ServiceTalk-Zoom.css"/>
```

In the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65764111/2287576) to my previous question they said about using `XPath` to locate all `link` nodes which have the attributes `rel="stylesheet"` and `type="text/css"`. But I am trying with LINQ 2 XML and can't work this out.

At the moment I have done the tests manually.

---

I have since learned that I can simplify the above code like this:

```
var strRel = (string)element.Attribute("rel") ?? "";
var strHref = (string)element.Attribute("href") ?? "";
```

Comment: I see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678251/find-elements-by-attribute-using-xdocument. Do I have to store the result of `Descendants` into an array and then use a `where` clause on that array?

Comment: I suppose since this is my own code we can ignore  the `type` attribute. So we are only interested in the other attributes.